# Is it possible to play pieces for cello on electric violin?

Tags: violin, cello

I want to learn to play violin and then switch to electric violin. I'm concerned if I technically can play pieces for cello or other 4-string instruments using electric violin as a sound signal generator - to post-process it later and get proper sound.

By "technically" I mean physical possibility: does the technique of playing violin allows me to reproduce the melody that I can play on cello? - Without breaking or twisting my arms and fingers.

P.S. I'm nooby musician right now, so my wording may be a little bit harsh - fill free to edit and improve my question.

Comment: Some version of any piece can be played on any instrument (with greater or lesser degrees of modification necessary depending on how different the instruments are). You should be able to play anything written for cello on the violin, but likely not in the same key, and certainly not in the same register. Most straightforward approach would be to transpose up a fifth - unless C string is not used in the piece, in which case you can play in the same key.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible to play pieces for violin that are were composed for cello. Check this out:

You might have to transcribe it a little, for example if a fingering position does get too awkward for you. But it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by 'electro-violin' you mean an instrument with the same relationship to violin as an electric guitar has to guitar, the answer is 'not really'.   You can put a microphone or pickup on a violin and process the sound.  You can pitch-shift it down an octave or two.  It may sound interesting.  It won't really become a cello.

It's not a lot different with an electric violin.

Comment: Hm, I meant electric violin as well too. Will edit my question. Anyway what do you mean exactly by 'not really'?